# Electron screen capture not getting the right content with fullscreen window

Tags: javascript, electron, desktopcapturer

I'm working in a project for Games Overlay using Electron with desktopCapturer to capture some screenshots from a fullscreen window outside electron. I'm using the default aproach you can find in the Electron documentation:

- Getting the source with `desktopCapturer.getSources()`;
- Starting the video stream with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`;
- Creating a  tag and set the video stream using `video.srcObject = stream`;
- Drawing the video content in a  with `ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` and exporting it using `callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));`

It works perfectly in almost all applications, but in this particularly fullscren game i have a problem:
It works fine and print the screen correctly UNTIL there is something ABOVE the game window, some examples:

1. Window menu open via window keyboard key;
2. Draging another notfullscreen window above it;
3. Overlay a transparent electron windown above it;

The result on the images generate by the canvas seems to be the last know state before the game is open: sometimes my desktop working area, sometimes another app that was opened at the time, and sometimes the loading screen from the game itself.

The solution i have now is hiding my overlay window before take a printscreen and showint it again after that, but i have to set a 100+- ms timeout to this solution work, and this is causing a ugly flickering in my overlay.

I tested the same code in some other fullscreen games and it worked just fine.

Any thoughts about it? I don't know if the problem could be in Electron or if the game has some window configuration that is causing this.

Thx in advance!

Comment: It could be anything, really. My bet is that the game (which game, btw?, someone might know more about it) does something weird with the graphics context of the GPU and thus screws up the way Chromium retrieves the image screen (I guess that it's something out of your control), but I may be fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner The game is Axie Infinity. As far as i know the game is made in unity if it might help. I tested in another games made in unity like Hearthstone and the problem do not occur. I was fearing this problem is out of my control, but stil hopping someone can give us a light. Thx for the answer!